# Starting a new activity issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a menu and when I click on register I want to open a new class with just one line of text in it.

The app opens and runs but when I click on the "Register" Button in my menu the app crashes. I have no code erros.

Can you see my issue?

```java
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    // Handle item selection    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {        
    case R.id.register: 

        Intent intent = new Intent(MeorNot.this, AddMember.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true; 
    }
}
```

This is my new class i try to open

```java
package com.meornotFinal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AddMember extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Add member");
        this.setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to add some more context to the OP. In it's current form, it will need to be guess work to try and figure out what the problem may be. And there must be errors in the logcat. I do have a clue of where the problem may be though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to set a ViewGroup as the top level item for an Activity's layout. Why are you adding the TextView like that and not using a layout XML?

Comment: Many developers believe that the logs contain useful information. It's a pity you don't have the faith.

Comment: Sorry i dont no how to use the log cat. I dont no how to get an enumerator installed. I have to put the apk on my phone to test. Its doesn recongize my phone when i have a usb plugged into it either.

Comment: this is not the way to develop applications my friend. Do some research and turn on the debugger and logcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your activity

```
<activity android:name="AddMember.class"> in AndroidManifest.xml file.
```

you are forgetting to add this line . so add this line also in androidmanifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a `View` in `setContentView()` instead of a `layout`

`this.setContentView(textview);`

If you are going to do it this way then you need to create a layout programmatically with something like

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

then you can add your `TextView` to this and set your layout in `setContentView()`

Unless you need to do it this way, a simpler way is probably to create the xml layout then get your `TextView` from there with `findViewById(R.id.textView1)` after calling `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);`

**Logcat**

To turn on the logcat, if not already in Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.

This will give you a console where it logs errors and other debug information. When your app crashes it will give you the reason and usually a java file with line number where it crashed. You may have to do further digging if the error happens before that line but it will give you a good starting point.

An example might be

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 08:24:02.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(334):     at your_app.org.ThisActivity.onCreate(ThisActivity.java:26)
```

Then you know to start looking at line 26 of `ThisActivity` for something that is null

Comment: You can set any view with setContentView, that's why it takes a view instead of a view group.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code block for the Activity you call after clicking on the *Register* button:

```
public class AddMember extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("Add member");
        this.setContentView(textview);

    }
}
```

You will need to change the `this.setContentView(textview);` to something like this:

```
public class AddMember extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_layout_in_your_layout_folder);

            // CAST YOUR TEXTVIEW HERE
    }
}
```

In the `a_layout_in_your_layout_folder`, you can keep a single `LinearLayout` and add your `TextView` at runtime. I don't quite see the point of doing such a thing as declaring a `TextView` in the layout XML would be a far simpler option.

But to each his own I suppose.

Comment: I picked up that code from a tutorial. I dont need the text there. I removed the text code and the class still crashes.

Comment: @CsharpBeginner: In that case, post your Manifest file in your OP.